# How to open other players for RTSP stream on iphone?

Tags: ios, rtsp

I'm trying to play rtsp stream in my apps on iphone. I'm not trying to write a player. I want the function like: when the user click the button then a window will pop out showing every players that support playing rtsp. when user click the player then the player will play the stream. I have google a lot but I can't even find a proper player for rtsp...so my questions are:

1. which player really works for playing rtsp? I have been try oplayer, but it didn't work...and other players that I tried even cannot play rtsp..
2. if I already install a player that can play rtsp, how to call and send the rtsp address to the player?

Answer (score 0):

This is classic Android intent behavior, unfortunately apple mobile devices do not multitask the way Android does.

Some time ago we tried to do something very similar only the task was to launch specific applications using voice commands.

We implemented custom url schemes for the player apps as described in this article.
http://sol3.typepad.com/tagalong_developer_journa/2012/01/in-this-segment-continuing-our-discussion-on-ios-external-accessories-and-multitasking-we-are-going-to-look-at-ways-an-applic.html

The schemes need to be defined for each of the players you need to launch, if these are apps you developed make sure to implement some method of passing the address via a url to the app, if these are third party players then you are dependent on wether the author included some kind of mechanism.

Now searching and discovering for players is another issue, if I can recall you can iterate through the list of custom url schemes and get the apps that are attached, that might be rather problematic, you probably are better off somehow keeping track of the apps that your application supports.

Seriously the iPhone just is not designed with this type of functionality in mind, I gave you some ideas here but I don't have a single good solution to your problem.

As to whats a good rtsp player, there are probably a few good ones in the app store or write your own using ffmpeg.

Seriously , you may be better off just building your own player supporting the formats you need rather than trying to implement some kind of player discovery and launching scheme.

Comment: Just implemented a player that works like this, we are running a beta, if your interested contact us